# Custom Post 404

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error

I'm attempting to create a custom post type (doctors) that will load a custom page template (single-doctors.php).  I've set up the custom post type through functions.php, and created a 'new doctor', selected the single-doctors template. 
 But when I go to actually see the page, the template doesnt load and I'm presented with a "This page not found" page. I've been scouring the interwebs trying to find a solution to this.  I find a lot of the same thing (flush permalinks, remove 'has_archive', etc.) but nothing has worked.

As a workaround, I tried downloading a custom post plugin (Custom Post Type UI) and setting things up that way.  This worked!!  But i will be doing more custom post creation on future sites and want to be able to do this without the plugin.  I tried taking the code generated by the plugin itself and replacing my code with theirs in my functions.php file.  This did not work and I was back to the "Page not found" page.  I'm pulling my hair out.  Can anybody help me identify what puzzle piece I'm missing?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  My functions.php code and the plugin's code below...

My code:

```
// Doctors
add_action( 'init', 'doctors_init' );
function doctors_init() {
        $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Doctors', 'post type general name', 'AIN' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Doctor', 'post type singular name', 'AIN' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Doctors', 'admin menu', 'AIN' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Doctor', 'add new on admin bar', 'AIN' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Doctor', 'AIN' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Doctor', 'AIN' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Doctor', 'AIN' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Doctor', 'AIN' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Doctor', 'AIN' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Doctors', 'AIN' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Doctors', 'AIN' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Doctors:', 'AIN' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Doctors found.', 'AIN' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Doctors found in Trash.', 'AIN' )
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "doctors", "understrap-child" ),
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'AIN' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'doctors', "with_front" => true ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => false,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-groups',
    );
    register_post_type( 'doctors', $args );
}
```

Plugin's Code:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_doctors2() {

    /**
     * Post Type: doctors2.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "doctors2", "understrap-child" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "doctor2", "understrap-child" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "doctors2", "understrap-child" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "doctors2", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "doctors2", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_doctors2' );
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Once you create a post type WP saves information about it and it's very difficult to change the permalinks. I would suggest using `unregister_post_type()` on both CPTs and then re-registering just one using the plugin code and your real desired slug. Also try registering the CPT as "doctor" rather than "doctors" (post types should be singular - sometimes that spare S can cause issues).

Comment: @WebElaine - Tried your suggestion. In my functions.php file, commented out the code for the custom post type, placed the unregister function for both 'doctor' and 'doctors', uploaded, refreshed permalinks, then deleted unregister function, UNcommented the register custom post code, changed 'doctors' to 'doctor', uploaded, refreshed permalinks, created a new 'doctor'....same thing, page not found.  The weirdest thing though, is this is working for a DIFFERENT custom post type ('nursing-homes') that I made previously at the same time as the initial doctors post type. Which just confuses me more

Comment: Are you visiting the link shown on the edit post screen? You have set `with_front` to `true`, which will prepend any static slug for the default `post` post type onto your CPT links. Otherwise, a copy / paste of your code works for me with latest WordPress and Twentysixteen theme. I suggest disabling all plugins, switching to a default theme, and testing if your code works in that case. After any code changes, just visit the permalinks settings page to flush rules, that's the only setting that persists for a CPT between requests, which is why post types must be registered on every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok all, I think I figured out the problem...well, problemS.  First, credit to @WebElaine, for putting me on the right track with the `unregister_post_type()` function.

I unregistered ALL of my post types, then went through and made sure everything was singular with no trailing S.  After unregistering everything (and commenting out any code that would register anything in the interim) I then went and refreshed my permalinks.  After that, I removed the unregistering function, and uncommented my previous code and allowed things to register.  This seemed to fix the issue and now the template is being read correctly.

Thank you all for the suggestions and help.  I'm a newly minted Jr Dev and am always blown away by the supportive dev community.  Hope anyone who lands here with the same frustration finds this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Comment out this lines:

```
    'has_archive'        => false,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
```

Then save permalinks in settings. Check if 404 error still appears. If not your problem is solved. You can uncomment those lines again if needed.

Comment: Commented those out, reset permalinks, same problem.  As my original post stated, I've tried this previously.  Thanks though. :-\

Comment: Huh, this code works for me on my installation. Aldo when i just copy / paste your code it has given me error 404. After that i just commented those lines refreshed permalinks and everything worked. Try removing single-doctors template, just to make sure that template does not making issues and disable all plugins. Maybe this will help :)